# How to replicate this specific curl query in Ruby/Ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, https, net-http

The following curl works perfectly fine.

```
curl -g "[external-url]" --data-urlencode 'JsonData={"TOKEN":"[token]","MID":"[merchant_id]"}'
```

But I am trying to replicate the same in Ruby/Ror.
The closest I have to is the following, but to no avail.

```
params = {JsonData: '{"TOKEN":"[token]","MID":"[merchant_id]"}'}
url = [external-url]
uri = URI(url)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
request.add_field('session_token', access_token)
request.body = params.to_json
response = Net::HTTP.start(
                            uri.hostname,
                            uri.port,
                            :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https' ,
                            :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
                           ) do |http|
        http.request(request)
      end
```

Comment: Why are you not using curb?